# Universe in the magnetic spectrum

Tags: cosmology

Can we scan the universe in magnetic spectrum and then separate the paramagnetic , diamagnetic and ferromagnetic objects and get a new picture of the cosmos.

Comment: What is the magnetic spectrum? The strength and orientation of magnetic fields of some objects can be determined via radio observations, but I don't believe it can be done for the ambient (and more prevalent) interstellar medium.

Comment: Yes; there could be some problems arising from the cosmic picture but we may get a new view of the universe and its objects.

Comment: I am not sure how we could get a new view since we can't actually do what you propose.

Comment: If we do the measurements part by part then is it possible.

Comment: The problem is that, as far as I know, paramagnetic, diamagnetic, and ferromagnetic apply only to solids and the universe is mostly plasma.

Comment: Additional to that is that you can't really tell the difference between the three without applying/removing an external field. That's certainly something we cannot do as well.

Comment: Firstly we have to propose a new theory on differentiating between tiny magnetic differences and then determine their type;  then we might get a chance to apply it on magnetism.

Answer (score 1):

No, we cannot scan the Universe using the "magnetic fields" only. Maxwell's equations of electromagnetism imply that the magnetic field from a magnetic dipole decreases as $1/r^3$. This is too fast a decrease for astronomical values of $r$ and reasonable size of the magnetic dipoles of the celestial bodies.

Instead, we observe the Universe via the electromagnetic spectrum (radio waves, microwaves, infrared, visible light, ultraviolet, X-ray, gamma rays). We use the fact that the electric fields induce magnetic ones and vice versa. The resulting electromagnetic waves contain both the electric and magnetic component and they propagate. The energy density or flux carried by the electromagnetic waves only decreases as $1/r^2$, and it is really constant locally when we focus on the source.

We can't "focus" on the magnetic source only because the magnetic fields without electromagnetic waves can't be directed in any way.

Moreover, as people point out, even if you could measure magnetic fields caused by celestial bodies really accurately at these huge distances, which you can't, you couldn't distinguish the three types of the source in any operational way. The magnetic field is locally always the same thing, fully determined by the intensity and the direction. It doesn't carry the information about the type of the magnetic material that created it. In this way, it differs from electromagnetic radiation that carries the additional information, the frequency, aside from the direction of the wave and perhaps its polarization. Electromagnetic waves carry much more information than static, e.g. magnetic, fields.